# Which information can we get it from Facebook application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So what i want is know what information can we get from an application recover a facebook account,
any help i will be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you should ask facebook user for allowing your application to access his data. It could be basic information, friend list, pages he has created, his actions,photos,likes etc. As far as customer allows your application to work with his data you could get everything you need.

I assume you could play a bit with Graph API explorer which could generate access tokens with different permissions. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.1